# Facebook doesn't take og:image

Tags: jquery, facebook, share

following Problem:

I am trying to set the og:image Metatag with jquery because i have several newsarticles. Some of them have Images and some of them not.
Thats why i have written in jquery that always the first image should be the og:image and if a article doesn´t have images a default og:image is set.

This works great but the Problem is, that facebook is not showing my og:image...

I have tested it several times with this tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

The jquery Code is very simple:

```
if($('.justified-gallery').length>0){
$('head').append("<meta property='og:image' content='http://myurl.at"+$(".justified-gallery a:first-of-type").attr("href")+"' />");
```

Maybe someone of you have an idea why facebook doesn´t take the og:image

thanks

Bernhard

Comment: I doubt Facebook even runs your javascript. They will just download the source of your page and read the tags. You need to create your tag server side before the page is served.

Comment: The OpenGraph meta tags need to be in the DOM when the page loads. Appending them dynamically via JS won't work as the reader interprets the source only, it does not execute JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook ignores JavaScript, you must use permanent/static OG tags. They will get cached too, so don´t change them all the time.